# Katta in nagamete itakatta

Tags: particles, て-form, tense

So, I was trying to make a translation, and I found nagamete itakatta. I thought it was referring to the te form and the past tense of iru combined, then there was katta, which I also thought was past tense, so I got really confused. I looked online, and katta was past tense, so I put it into DeepL Translate, and it said that katta in itakatta was want? what, give an explanation please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 眺めてい**た**かった
> [Someone] **wanted** to keep/stay/be watching it.

眺めていたかった is the past form of 眺めてい**たい**, which is the [tai- (or desire) form](https://thetruejapan.com/tai-form-in-japanese/) of 眺めている. There is no "past tense of iru" in this sentence; the past marker is used only once at the end of the sentence.

-たい follows the masu-stem of a verb and conjugates like an i-adjective. Just as the past form of かたい ("hard") is かたかった, the past form of -たい is -たかった.

- 食べたい。
  I want to eat it.
- 食べたかった。
  I wanted to eat it.
- 食べていたい。
  I want to be/keep eating it. (progressive)
- 食べていたかった。
  I wanted to be/keep eating it.

Comment: oh i didnt know it was used with the te form

Comment: @StarPeep, be careful here -- I think you might be confused.  The ～たい desiderative ending here is on the verb いる, and is **_not_** attaching to the ～て form of 食【た】べる.  Let's break this down fully: 食【た】べていたかった = 食【た】べ (stem of 食【た】べる "to eat") + ～て (conjunctive suffix) + い (stem of いる "to be", here used for present progressive "to be `[VERB]`-ing") + ～た (stem of ～たい desiderative suffix) + ～かった (past tense for ～い adjectives).

Comment: ohhhhhh. how did i not know iru had a tai form as well,